# How to plot an equation with multiple variables in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Suppose I have a variable list z

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I am trying to plot the equation

```
y = 1a + 2b + 3c + 4d + 5e + 6f + 7g + 8h + 9i + 10k
```

I am confused on how to plot a multi dimensional equation in python. I use the matplotlib library now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
equation="y ="
for i in range(len(z)):
    if i>0:
        equation=equation+" +"
    equation=equation+" "+str(z[i])+chr(ord('a')+i)
print equation
```

The output is:

```
y = 1a + 2b + 3c + 4d + 5e + 6f + 7g + 8h + 9i + 10j
```